# How do I define a work week in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to split a report by work week, and our work week is Saturday through Friday.  How would I convert an ISO week from DATEPART(WW, ) into a work week?

Comment: I don't know what an ISO week is, but maybe this can help "...WHERE DATEPART(dw, yourDate) <> 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) to be saturday:

```
SET DATEFIRST 6;
```

Check the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) documentation regarding the ISO week for how this affects things.

Comment: Yep this was the problem.  I removed datefirst because it made another function come out correct that was actually incorrectly written.  

The other function came out wrong because while in development I forgot to set datefirst on it and instead corrected it with increments, but my DbConnection in my app WAS setting datefirst so it came out wrong.

Basically I was a dummy, and the program is working in both functions instead of me swapping logic errors between them.

Answer (score 1):

SET DATEFIRST 6